# Raspberry Pi 4 curl/curl.h no such file in Alexa Voice Service

Tags: curl, raspberry-pi4, alexa-voice-service

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 model B and trying to install the Alexa Voice Service onto it. I was following this tutorial: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-voice-service/build-the-avs-device-sdk.html

I was able to execute their 3 `wget` commands. Then tried to run the serial number line, but it stops and gets an error. Something about a missing `curl/curl.h` file. I do have curl installed on my Pi OS. Here is the stacktrace:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo bash setup.sh config.json [-s MY_SERIAL_NUMBER]
################################################################################
################################################################################


AVS Device SDK Raspberry pi Script - Terms and Agreements


The AVS Device SDK is dependent on several third-party libraries, environments, 
and/or other software packages that are installed using this script from 
third-party sources ("External Dependencies"). These are terms and conditions 
associated with the External Dependencies 
(available at https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/wiki/Dependencies) that 
you need to agree to abide by if you choose to install the External Dependencies.


If you do not agree with every term and condition associated with the External 
Dependencies, enter "QUIT" in the command line when prompted by the installer.
Else enter "AGREE".


################################################################################
################################################################################
AGREE
################################################################################
Proceeding with installation
################################################################################
[  0%] Building CXX object AVSCommon/CMakeFiles/AVSCommon.dir/AVS/src/Attachment/Attachment.cpp.o
[  0%] Building CXX object AVSCommon/CMakeFiles/AVSCommon.dir/AVS/src/AlexaClientSDKInit.cpp.o
/home/pi/avs-device-sdk/AVSCommon/AVS/src/AlexaClientSDKInit.cpp:16:10: fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <curl/curl.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[3]: *** [AVSCommon/CMakeFiles/AVSCommon.dir/build.make:141: AVSCommon/CMakeFiles/AVSCommon.dir/AVS/src/AlexaClientSDKInit.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:5064: AVSCommon/CMakeFiles/AVSCommon.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:15235: SampleApp/src/CMakeFiles/SampleApp.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:3568: SampleApp] Error 2
```

In my research, I found this article, but it's for Pi 3 Buster. It seems to be the closest to the issue I'm having, but there was no solution I could understand. https://github.com/alexa/avs-device-sdk/issues/1464

It seems like the error message is saying the curl file is missing in their SDK. Is that right?

What can I do to make the serial number command work?

Answer (score 1):

Since I am new to Raspberry Pi, I didn't realize what the library installation system was like. I had tried to install cURL to the /home/pi folder, but needed to install it in the root. Once I did, my serial number command worked perfectly.

Here is what I used to install cURL:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```